Find out $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+ax+1}{1+x^4}\arctan\frac1x\,{\rm d}x$.
$$
\mbox{Find out}\quad\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + ax +1}{1 + x^{4}}\,\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right){\rm d}x
$$
My attempt:
\begin{align}I &= \int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^2 + ax + 1}{1 + x^4}\,\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right){\rm d}x
\\[2mm] & = \int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^2 + ax + x}{1 + x^4}\,\arctan\left(x\right)
{\rm d}x\qquad\qquad \left[x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}\right]
\\[2mm] \implies 2I & = \int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\left(x^{2} + ax + 1\right)
\left[\arctan\left(1/x\right) + \arctan\left(x\right)\right]}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x
\\[2mm] & =
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + ax + 1}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x
\end{align}
No idea how to proceed (I'm expecting cooler approaches without Feymann here) .

I guess you made a mistake when applying the substitution. The denominator, after the substitution has been applied, should also be $\mathrm{x}^2+a\mathrm{x}+1$.

Mathematica:  $\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 \left(a n+2 \sqrt{2}\right)$

We have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + ax + 1}{1 + x^4} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=$$$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 +1}{1 + x^4} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx+a\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1 + x^4} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$$$=I+a\cdot J$$
For the integral $I$, notice that using the change $x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ we get $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2} \frac{\dfrac{1}{x^2}+1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{x^4}} \arctan(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \arctan(x)\,dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+x^2}{1 + x^4}\,dx-I$$
where in the last equality we have used $\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\arctan(1/x)$ for $x>0$.
The integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+x^2}{1 + x^4}\,dx$ is immediate (using partial fractions, one gets $\arctan$ type integrals) and is equal to $\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.
This means that $$I=\dfrac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2}}-I\implies I=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{2}}$$
A similar approach can be used for $J$: the change $x\mapsto\dfrac{1}{x}$ yields $$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2} \frac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{1 + \dfrac{1}{x^4}} \arctan(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^4+1} \arctan(x)\,dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{x^4+1}\,dx-J$$
A primitive for that last integrand is $\dfrac{\arctan(x^2)}{2}$, which means that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{x^4+1}\,dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.
Thus, $$J=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-J\implies J=\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}$$
Putting both of these results together, we conclude $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 + ax + 1}{1 + x^4} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=I+a\cdot J=\pi^2\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{a}{16}\right)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}(a+2\sqrt{2})$$

As $$
I \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2+a x+1\right) \arctan x}{1+x^4},
$$
Average them and then using $\arctan  x+\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ yields
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2+a x+1}{1+x^4} d x= \frac{\pi}{4} J(a)
$$
Differentiating $J(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ gives
$$
J^{\prime}(a) =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^4} d x =\frac{1}{2}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(x^2\right)\right]_0^{\infty} =\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
Integrating backward, we have
$$
J(a)-J(0)=\int_0^a \frac{\pi}{4} d u=\frac{\pi a}{4}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(0) & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2} \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left.x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{2}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back concludes
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{4} J(a) =\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{\pi a}{4}+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\right) =\frac{\pi^2}{16}(a+2 \sqrt{2})
$$

Let us take your evaluation of
$$I:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+ax+1}{1+x^4}\arctan\frac1x\,{\rm d}x$$
where you left it:
$$\begin{align}2I &=\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+ax+1}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x\\
\implies\frac{4I}\pi&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{(x\sqrt2+1)^2+1}+\frac1{(x\sqrt2-1)^2+1}\right){\rm d}x+\frac a2\int_0^\infty\frac{2x}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left([\arctan]_1^\infty+[\arctan]_{-1}^\infty\right)+\frac a2[\arctan]_0^\infty\\
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}+\frac{a\pi}4\\
\implies I&=\frac{\pi^2}{16}\left(2\sqrt2+a\right).\end{align}$$

My Compilation
$$\begin{align}I &= \int_0^\infty\frac{x^2 + ax + 1}{1 + x^4} \arctan\frac1x\,{\rm d}x\\&= \int_0^\infty\frac{x^2 + ax + x}{1 + x^4} \arctan x\,{\rm d}x\quad [x → \frac1x]
\\\implies2I&= \int_0^\infty\frac{(x^2+ax+1)\left(\arctan\frac1x+\arctan x\right)}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x\\&=\frac\pi2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+ax+1}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x\\ \implies I &= \frac\pi4 \int_0^\infty\frac{x^2 + ax + 1}{1+x^4}{\rm d}x\\&= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}{\rm d}x+ \int_0^\infty\frac{ax}{x^4 + 1}{\rm d}x\\&= \left[\frac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt2x}+ \frac a2\arctan(x^2)\right]_{x = 0}^\infty\\&= \frac{\pi^2 a}{16}.\end{align}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}{\rm d}x\ne\left[\frac1{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt2x}\right]_{x = 0}^\infty$$

@AnneBauval thanx for pointing out
